# Android project Build, Gradle error

Tags: android, git, gradle

I am trying to build a project, which is extracted from Github. However building it results in `CreateProcess error=2` `The system cannot find the file specified` . [This is the project I am building.](https://github.com/fossasia/open-event-android)

And here is the `build.gradle` file code:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def gitSha = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
def buildTime = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

def isTravis = "true".equals(System.getenv("TRAVIS"))
def preDexEnabled = "true".equals(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    dexOptions {
        // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
        preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !isTravis
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.fossasia.openevent"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime}\""
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        fdroid {
        }
        googleplay {
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'

    googleplayCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'

    fdroidCompile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
    fdroidCompile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.slf4j.api:1.7.2'
    fdroidCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"

}
```

Since this is the first time I am building another project from Git, I am clueless where I am doing wrong. The past questions too doesnt seems helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It should be because  of this line proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt').

Comment: The file should be missing or it is not in the intended path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Git" bin folder location to Environment path. I too had the same issue. I've added the Git to Windows Environment variables and tried the command  'git rev-parse --short HEAD' in command prompt and it was working. Then after restarting the studio, the error was gone.

Comment: How to add? Please list step by step